# How to reload the main viewcontroller after swipe gesture action

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, dismiss

Hi I am using following code for dismiss to view controller with swipe action by using Gestures.

Here I present the screen with button action.

in presented screen I dismiss with the swipe action after dismissing I want to reload the main view.

```
let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Pickup", bundle: nil)
let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CleaningnoteController")as! CleaningnoteController
vc.dcnote = self.dryclean
vc.scheduleid = String(scheduleId)
self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

//IN presented screen.
Here uiview is the added view on the Viewcontroller.

var initialTouchPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
let get = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pangectureRecognizer))
self.uiview.addGestureRecognizer(get)


//Swipe Action.

@objc func pangectureRecognizer(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

  let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.view?.window)

  if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
     initialTouchPoint = touchPoint
  } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
    if touchPoint.y - initialTouchPoint.y > 0 {
       self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: touchPoint.y - initialTouchPoint.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    }
  } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.cancelled {
     if touchPoint.y - initialTouchPoint.y > 100 {
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
     } else {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
         self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
     })
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: You can set a callback or notification for reloading the main view controller.

Comment: Use a delegate to reload the presenting view controller before dismissing the presented view controller if you want to get a head start on it.